# Proof of normalization constant of wave function to be independent of time

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, probability, normalization

I am trying to prove that the normalization constant is independent of time. If we have fixed it for a particular time then it will remain constant for all time.

Suppose $\psi(x,t)$ is a wavefunction.
Let $A(t)$ be the normalization constant of $\psi(x,t)$
Then $\displaystyle A^*A\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\psi(x,t)|^2dx=1\tag{1}$
$\displaystyle \implies \frac{d}{dt}A^*A\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\psi(x,t)|^2dx=0\tag{2}$
$\displaystyle \implies\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\psi(x,t)|^2dx\frac{d}{dt}A^*A+A^*A\frac{d}{dt}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\psi(x,t)|^2dx=0\tag{3}$

Now first analyze, $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dt}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\psi(x,t)|^2dx$
$\displaystyle \frac{d}{dt}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\psi(x,t)|^2dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|\psi(x,t)|^2dx\tag{4}$
$\displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial t}|\psi(x,t)|^2dx=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\psi^*\psi)dx=\psi^*\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial t}=\psi\frac{\partial\psi^*}{\partial t}\tag{5}$
By time dependent Schrodinger equation
$\displaystyle \frac{\partial\psi}{\partial t}=\frac{i\bar{h}}{2m}\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial x^2}-\frac{i}{\bar{h}}V\psi\tag{6}$
Also, $\displaystyle \frac{\partial\psi^*}{\partial t}=-\frac{i\bar{h}}{2m}\frac{\partial^2\psi^*}{\partial x^2}+\frac{i}{\bar{h}}V\psi^*\tag{7}$

So, $\displaystyle \frac{\partial|\psi|^2}{\partial t}=\psi^*\Big(\frac{i\bar{h}}{2m}\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial x^2}-\frac{i}{\bar{h}}V\psi\Big)+\psi\Big(-\frac{i\bar{h}}{2m}\frac{\partial^2\psi^*}{\partial x^2}+\frac{i}{\bar{h}}V\psi^*\Big)\tag{8}$
$\displaystyle \implies\frac{\partial|\psi|^2}{\partial t}=\frac{i\bar{h}}{2m}\Big(\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial x^2}-\frac{\partial^2\psi^*}{\partial x^2}\Big)\tag{9}$
$\displaystyle \implies\frac{\partial|\psi|^2}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big[\frac{i\bar{h}}{2m}\Big(\psi^*\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}-\psi\frac{\partial\psi^*}{\partial x}\Big)\Big]\tag{10}$
$\displaystyle \frac{d}{dt}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\psi(x,t)|^2dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big[\frac{i\bar{h}}{2m}\Big(\psi^*\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}-\psi\frac{\partial\psi^*}{\partial x}\Big)\Big]dx\tag{11}$
$\displaystyle \implies\frac{d}{dt}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\psi(x,t)|^2dx=\frac{i\bar{h}}{2m}\Big(\psi^*\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}-\psi\frac{\partial\psi^*}{\partial x}\Big)\Big|_{-\infty}^\infty\tag{12}$
As $\displaystyle \psi(x,t)\to0$ as $x\to\pm\infty$.
So, $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dt}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\psi(x,t)|^2dx=0\tag{13}$
So, $(3)$ becomes
$\displaystyle \implies\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\psi(x,t)|^2dx\frac{d}{dt}A^*A=0\tag{14}$
As $\psi$ is square integrable, so $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\psi(x,t)|^2dx=c$ where $c\in\mathbb R$ and $c\neq 0$
So, $\frac{d}{dt}A^*A=0\tag{15}$
$\implies |A|^2=constant\tag{16}$

I have the following doubts from the proof
**(i)** From $(11)$ to $(12)$, in the RHS, we have used fundamental theorem of calculus.
Ingtegrating of the derivative is the antiderivative. $\int_a^bf'(x)dx=f(x)$. But here the condition is that f has to continuous and differentiable on $[a,b]$ with $f'$ integrable on $[a,b]$.
So, in $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big[\frac{i\bar{h}}{2m}\Big(\psi^*\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}-\psi\frac{\partial\psi^*}{\partial x}\Big)\Big]dx$,
we take $\Big(\psi^*\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}-\psi\frac{\partial\psi^*}{\partial x}\Big)$ to be continuous. As $\psi$ and $\psi^*$ is continuous, this means that $\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}$ is also continuous.
But we know in general that first derivative of $\psi$ can be discontinuous also. So how we have used fundamental theorem of calculus here?

**(ii)** From $(12)$ to $(13)$, we have taken $\frac{i\bar{h}}{2m}\Big(\psi^*\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}-\psi\frac{\partial\psi^*}{\partial x}\Big)\Big|_{-\infty}^\infty=0$ using the fact that $\psi\to 0$ as $x\to\pm\infty$. But this also means that $\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}\to 0$ as $x\to\pm\infty$. But how we can be sure that $\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}$ is bounded?

**(iii)** In $(16)$, we get $|A|^2=constant$. But from this how we get $A(t)=constant$.
$|A|^2$ constant means that magnitude of the vector in complex plane is constant but it might happen that the angle of $A$ changes. This angle changes as a function of $t$. So how we conclude that $A$ is independent of time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this completely rigorous, you would have to delve into [functional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_analysis). But I will try to explain it intuitively.

**(i)** Arguably all derivatives of $\psi$ are continuous in reality. Non-smooth functions are an idealization, but a useful one. They can be formalized using [distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)). Even when $f$ is discontinuous, $f'$ is *defined* to be something that integrates to $f$. The results are equivalent to considering smooth functions and taking a *limit* in which they develop a discontinuity or kink.

**(ii)** The wave function must have a *real* expectation value of kinetic energy on physical grounds. The kinetic energy operator is proportional to $-\partial^2/\partial x^2$ and has an expectation value proportional to
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\, \psi^* \left(-\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial x^2}\right) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\, \left|\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}\right|^2 - \left.\psi^* \frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}\right|_{-\infty}^\infty.$$
The imaginary part of this is precisely proportional to your key expression, $(\psi^*\, \partial\psi/\partial x - \psi\, \partial\psi^*/\partial x)|_{-\infty}^\infty$, which must therefore be zero. (Technically, the wave function must be defined in a space where the energy operator is Hermitian.)

**(iii)** The Schrödinger equation fully determines the evolution of the wave function $\psi$, and what you have shown is that if $\psi$ is initially normalized ($|A| = 1$) then it remains normalized ($|A|$ remains $1$). By saying that $A$ is the normalization constant, you have only defined its *magnitude*. So indeed the *phase* of $A$ is arbitrary, but it is *not part of the wave function*. Given that $|A| = 1$, you can simply write the normalization condition as $\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\, |\psi|^2 = 1$. Ultimately, $A$ is a redundant, unphysical parameter.

Answer (score 5):

If the Hamiltonian is time-independent, then it seems much simpler to use
$$
\vert\Psi(t)\rangle = e^{-i \hat H t/\hbar}\vert\Psi(0)\rangle\, .
$$
Then it is automatic that
\begin{align}
\langle \Psi(t)\vert\Psi(t)\rangle &= \langle \Psi(0)\vert 
e^{i\hat H t/\hbar} e^{-i \hat H t/\hbar}\vert \Psi(0)\rangle\, ,\\
&=\langle \Psi(0)\vert \Psi(0)\rangle
\end{align}
since $e^{i\hat H t/\hbar}e^{-i \hat H t/\hbar}=\mathbb{1}$.

If the Hamiltonian is time dependent, then the evolution operator $U(t)$ is constructed to be unitary, so that
\begin{align}
\vert\Psi(t)\rangle &= U(t)\vert\Psi(0)\rangle \, ,\\
\langle \Psi(0)\vert U^\dagger(t)U(t)\vert \Psi(0)\rangle&=
\langle \Psi(0)\vert \Psi(0)\rangle
\end{align}
as $U^\dagger(t)U=\mathbb{1}$ by construction.

The wavefunction version follows in the same way:
\begin{align}
\Psi(x,t)&=e^{-i \hat H t/\hbar}\Psi(x,0)\, ,\\
\Psi(x,t)&=U(t)\Psi(x,0)
\end{align}
for the time-independent and the time-dependent cases, respectively.

Comment: IMO, by using such abstract Hilbert-space notation, this answer skips over OP's core difficulty, which is understanding in what sense the naive position-space Schrödinger equation satisfies these Hilbert-space properties (e.g., the ability to use distributions and not just functions for $\psi$, and the precise Hermitian property of the differential operator $\hat H$). It's not quite enough to say "$\psi$ is a function" or even "$\psi$ is a square-integrable function". That's why I pointed OP to functional analysis.

Comment: @nanoman but then this is another question altogether as it would have nothing to do with preserving the normalization over time, but rather showing that $\psi$ is a “legal” state and can be normalized at any time.

Comment: But it turns out that preserving the normalization in position space essentially amounts to deriving the Hermitian property of the differential operator $\hat H$, so it brings to the fore the question of precisely what function space $\psi$ lives in.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding (i), I am still not sure what you are asking. In general, $d\psi/dx$ is continuous over an interval if the potential $V(x)$ is finite within that interval. At the boundaries, if the potential $V(x) \to \pm \infty$, then $d\psi/dx$ is **no longer continuous.** Therefore, the continuity of the first derivative of the wavefunction depends on the behavior of the potential.

(See, for example, Griffiths' *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics* Chapter 2, Section 2.5.2 The Delta-Function Well.)

Regarding (ii), for a physical system, the wavefunctions "decays" to zero as one approaches $\pm \infty$ on the real position axis -- otherwise the system is unphysical. This means the wavefunction eventually becomes flat, implying its first derivative is zero.

Regarding (iii), you are correct in that $A$ might have some "angular" dependence. This is called *phase dependence* and is mostly inconsequential in Quantum Mechanics. You can always isolate the phase as follows: $A(t) = |A| \, e^{i\, \phi(t)}$. After that, once you evaluate $|A|^2 = A(t)^* A(t)$, the phase factor reduces to unity.

Comment: I have understood your point. But I have a question that does $d\psi/dx$ has to be bounded in general also? Can you also clarify my doubt i)?

Comment: @Iti I have edited my answer.

Comment: If $F$ is a continuous function function over $(a,b)$ and differentiable over $[a,b]$ and derivative of $F$ is integrable over that interval, then by fundamental theorem of calculus $\int\frac{dF}{dx}dx=F+c$. So by analogy with RHS of the equation $(11)$, $\frac{d\psi}{dx}$ has to be continuous. But if the potential is dirac delta function then $\frac{d\psi}{dx}$ has a jump at that point meaning not continuous. So in general how can we use fundamental theorem of calculus in $(11)$?

Comment: "the wavefunction eventually becomes flat, implying its first derivative is zero" -- this isn't strictly sufficient, because $\psi$ could conceivably approach zero with oscillations that decay in amplitude but become more and more rapid as $x \to \pm\infty$, so $\partial\psi/\partial x$ would not go to zero.